# Explanation of using 'had had'

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

We wish that we had had more time last night.

Why 'had' used twice here?

Comment: Hello, faisal. Please look up the term 'past perfect'. Basic English is better asked about on our sister site, ELL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "had had" mean? How does this differ from "had"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2658/what-does-had-had-mean-how-does-this-differ-from-had)

Comment: One key difference is it's perfectly possible to say *We wish that we **had** more time **tomorrow***, but it's logically almost impossible to say *We wish that we **had had** more time tomorrow* (but *just about* possible with ***tonight***, provided time of utterance is very late in the evening).

Comment: Two different meanings of "had".

Answer (score 1):

`I wish I had had…` is a way to talk about past wishes that weren't fulfilled. You can read more about this [here](https://www.englishgrammar.org/expressing-wishes-english/):

> To talk about past wishes, we can use the structure I wish I had had…
>   Note that the second had in this structure is the past participle form
>   of have. Past participle forms of other verbs are also possible in
>   this case.

In your sentence, *We wish that we had had more time last night*, *they* wanted to have more time last night but *they* didn't and so *they* regret it now.

Answer (score 1):

The first "had" is an auxiliary verb that is used to form the [perfect aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_(grammar)). The second is a verb indicating possession or experience. Basically, they are different verbs that have the same form.